# How to add a virtual core to Linux system

Tags: linux, cpu

Here a virtual core means another CPU core that does not exist physically but can exist just as another core and can be assigned processes naturally by the system.

Is it even possible to do this?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a virtual core to a virtual machine by making use of the hypervisor controls. It is not possible to do so to a physical machine outside of something like turning on hyperthreading int he BIOS (assuming it's not already on).